# How can I add New Column and it's data using google chart api

Tags: html, google-visualization, linechart

I have Idea how can I add new Person after 'George' and it's data for year Jan to April dynamically. How can I achieve my desired result? Here is the code which I'm using :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Wilson', 'Jennifer','George'],
      ['Jan',  1000,      400,88],
      ['Feb',  1170,      460,99],
      ['March',  660,       1120,55],
      ['April',  1030,      540,33]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' },
      pointSize: 20,
      pointShape: 'square'

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
    //data.addColumn('summit');
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain better what are you trying to do? What are you getting and what's the desired result?

Comment: I want to add a new column and column's data dynamically . Whitehat answer my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the [`addColumn`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_addColumn) method
you can save the returned column index to update the rows
incase you want to add multiple columns

in the following example, the values for the new column are calculated from a previous column

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Wilson', 'Jennifer','George'],
    ['Jan',  1000,      400,88],
    ['Feb',  1170,      460,99],
    ['March',  660,       1120,55],
    ['April',  1030,      540,33]
  ]);

  var colIndex = data.addColumn('number', 'New');
  for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    data.setValue(i, colIndex, data.getValue(i, colIndex - 1) * 2);
  }

  var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    curveType: 'function',
    legend: { position: 'bottom' },
    pointSize: 20,
    pointShape: 'square'

  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```